# Which linkages are granted to non-local member variables in c++?

Tags: c++, class, linkage

I assume that a class's data members have linkage(or no linkage) like below
Is that correct?

```
class AAA {
public:                          // this doesn't matter

  int var1;                      // no linkage
  const int var2 = 0;            // no linkage

  static int var3;               // external linkage (declaration)
  static const int var4 = 0;     // external linkage (declaration + definition)

};

int AAA::var3 = 0; // external linkage (definition)
```

Comment: Your linkage comments are correct, but `var4` is not a definition. Its value can be used in contexts that don't require the definition to exist

Comment: @M.M thank you for your answer, now I knew that it doesn't have any memory location to save its value.. if then how can I call it properly?  declaration..? or substitution...?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I questioned about which linkages are granted to data members
and my assumption was right and M.M answered it's OK too
I double checked in the standard and yes, linkages are correct like I and M.M said above

But as M.M mentioned I misunderstood which one is declaration or definition
It's a bit out of topic but I answer it by myself for someone who read this in future

[1] if it comes to non-static data member

```
struct A {
  int var1;        // definition (initial value is 0)
  int var2 = 100;  // definition (initial value is 100)
};
```

[2] if it comes to static const

```
struct A {
  static const int var1 = 100; // declaration (initial value is 100)
  static const int var2;       // declaration (initial value is 0)
};

const int A::var1;             // definition (an option for odr-used situation)
const int A::var2 = 10;        // definition
```

[3] if it comes to static constexpr

`constexpr` data members are interesting and work differently
because from C++17 a data member with `constexpr` implies `inline`
and `inline` actually define it

plus every `inline` data members in every translation units are guaranteed to have same only one definition
(https://eel.is/c++draft/depr.static.constexpr)

```
struct A {
  static constexpr int n = 5;   // definition (declaration in C++ 2014)
};

constexpr int A::n;             // redundant declaration (definition in C++ 2014)
```

for example if I have 2 translation units like below

```cpp
// foo.cpp
#include <iostream>

class AAA {
public:
    static constexpr int var = 10; 
};

void foo() {
    std::cout << &AAA::var << std::endl;
}

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

class AAA {
public:
    static constexpr int var = 10; 
};

void foo();

int main() {
    std::cout << &AAA::var << std::endl;
    foo();
}
```

and result is like below

```sh
$ g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp foo.cpp
$ ./a.out 
0x564ba82a3a54
0x564ba82a3a54
```